# SAS proc Tabulate, Order by specific variable

Tags: sas, proc, tabulate

I am using ficticious numbers as I cannot publish the original dataset. I have the following SAS-Code:

```
PROC TABULATE DATA=table;
TITLE 'Offences per country and year;
CLASS year country offence_type;
TABLES country, year ALL, region /BOX="" MISSTEXT='0';
RUN;
```

This gives me for every country a table like this.

```
SWITZERLAND
year | theft | robbery | assault | …
------------------------------------
ALL  |  1302       329       100   …
1980 |   321       100        24   … 
1981 |   280        24        20   … 
   … |     …         …         …   …
```

Now, I'd like to change the order of the offence-types / columns. The most frequent offence-types (over all years) should appear on the left side and the less frequent offence-types should appear on the
right side (as in the example above).

I've already tried `/ ORDER=FREQ` after the `TABLES`-statement, but then also the order of the years gets changed.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Why is `region` not in `CLASS` or `VAR`, or should `region` in `TABLES` be `offence_type` ?  What does in input data set look like ?  Is it one row per offence ?

Answer (score 1):

Specify the `offence_type` variable in a separate `CLASS` statement that uses the `ORDER=FREQ` option.

Example:

- First tabulate shows class order is data ascending,
- Second tabulate shows the effect of `CLASS <var>/ ORDER=FREQ`.
- Third tabulate shows the additional effect of `BY <group-vars>` (and some trickery to avoid title above each `BY` group).

```
ods listing;

options 
  pagesize=1000
  nodate nonumber nocenter
  formdlim=' '
  formchar="|----|+|---+=|-/\<>*"
;

dm 'listing; clear';

data have(index=(country));
  do country = 'Zeroland   ', 'Switzerland', 'Crimeland';
    do year = 1980 to year(today());
      date = mdy(1,1,year);
      do date = date to intnx('year',date,1);
        crime = scan ('theft robbery assault parking', min(4,rand('geometric', 0.6)));

        /***********************************************\
        |* edit, make robbery predominant in Crimeland *|
        \***********************************************/
        if country = 'Crimeland' then do;
          crime = scan ('robbery theft assault parking', min(4,rand('geometric', 0.6)));
        end;

        output;
      end;
    end;
  end;

  format date date9.;
run;
```

Tabulates

```
proc tabulate data=have NOSEPS format=8.;
  title1 "Tabulate: default class ordering Alphabetical";
  *where country like 'S%' and year < 1984;
  where year < 1982;
  class country year ;
  class crime;
  tables country, ALL year, crime / condense;
run;

proc tabulate data=have NOSEPS format=8.;
  title1 "Tabulate: CLASS / order=freq - crimes Frequency Descending";
  title2 "freq ordering based on all data";
  * where country like 'S%' and year < 1984;
  where year < 1982;

  class country year ;
  class crime / order=freq;
  tables ALL country, ALL year, crime / condense;
run;

data for_tabulate(index=(country));
  set have;
  title1 = 'NOBYLINE, TITLE in Data. / order=freq by group';
  title2 = 'Country ' || country;
run;

options nobyline;

proc tabulate data=for_tabulate NOSEPS format=8.;
  title;
  * where country like 'S%' and year < 1984;
  where year < 1982;

  by country;

  class title1 title2 year ;
  class crime / order=freq;
  tables 
    title1 * title2,
    ALL year,
    crime 
    / condense
    ;
run;
```

Listing output

**Alphabetical**

```
Tabulate: default class ordering Alphabetical

country Crimeland
------------------------------------------------------------
|                      |               crime               |
|                      |-----------------------------------|
|                      |assault |parking |robbery | theft  |
|                      |--------+--------+--------+--------|
|                      |   N    |   N    |   N    |   N    |
|----------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------|
|All                   |      69|      50|     438|     176|
|year                  |        |        |        |        |
|1980                  |      39|      29|     214|      85|
|1981                  |      30|      21|     224|      91|
------------------------------------------------------------

country Switzerland
------------------------------------------------------------
|                      |               crime               |
|                      |-----------------------------------|
|                      |assault |parking |robbery | theft  |
|                      |--------+--------+--------+--------|
|                      |   N    |   N    |   N    |   N    |
|----------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------|
|All                   |      70|      44|     178|     441|
|year                  |        |        |        |        |
|1980                  |      42|      27|      84|     214|
|1981                  |      28|      17|      94|     227|
------------------------------------------------------------

country Zeroland
------------------------------------------------------------
|                      |               crime               |
|                      |-----------------------------------|
|                      |assault |parking |robbery | theft  |
|                      |--------+--------+--------+--------|
|                      |   N    |   N    |   N    |   N    |
|----------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------|
|All                   |      74|      38|     189|     432|
|year                  |        |        |        |        |
|1980                  |      36|      25|      89|     217|
|1981                  |      38|      13|     100|     215|
------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Frequency (over all) descending**

```
Tabulate: CLASS / order=freq - crimes Frequency Descending
freq ordering based on all data

All
------------------------------------------------------------
|                      |               crime               |
|                      |-----------------------------------|
|                      | theft  |robbery |assault |parking |
|                      |--------+--------+--------+--------|
|                      |   N    |   N    |   N    |   N    |
|----------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------|
|All                   |    1049|     805|     213|     132|
|year                  |        |        |        |        |
|1980                  |     516|     387|     117|      81|
|1981                  |     533|     418|      96|      51|
------------------------------------------------------------

country Crimeland
------------------------------------------------------------
|                      |               crime               |
|                      |-----------------------------------|
|                      | theft  |robbery |assault |parking |
|                      |--------+--------+--------+--------|
|                      |   N    |   N    |   N    |   N    |
|----------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------|
|All                   |     176|     438|      69|      50|
|year                  |        |        |        |        |
|1980                  |      85|     214|      39|      29|
|1981                  |      91|     224|      30|      21|
------------------------------------------------------------

country Switzerland
------------------------------------------------------------
|                      |               crime               |
|                      |-----------------------------------|
|                      | theft  |robbery |assault |parking |
|                      |--------+--------+--------+--------|
|                      |   N    |   N    |   N    |   N    |
|----------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------|
|All                   |     441|     178|      70|      44|
|year                  |        |        |        |        |
|1980                  |     214|      84|      42|      27|
|1981                  |     227|      94|      28|      17|
------------------------------------------------------------

country Zeroland
------------------------------------------------------------
|                      |               crime               |
|                      |-----------------------------------|
|                      | theft  |robbery |assault |parking |
|                      |--------+--------+--------+--------|
|                      |   N    |   N    |   N    |   N    |
|----------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------|
|All                   |     432|     189|      74|      38|
|year                  |        |        |        |        |
|1980                  |     217|      89|      36|      25|
|1981                  |     215|     100|      38|      13|
------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Frequency (over BY group) descending**

```
title1 NOBYLINE, TITLE in Data. / order=freq by group
and title2 Country Crimeland
------------------------------------------------------------
|                      |               crime               |
|                      |-----------------------------------|
|                      |robbery | theft  |assault |parking |
|                      |--------+--------+--------+--------|
|                      |   N    |   N    |   N    |   N    |
|----------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------|
|All                   |     438|     176|      69|      50|
|year                  |        |        |        |        |
|1980                  |     214|      85|      39|      29|
|1981                  |     224|      91|      30|      21|
------------------------------------------------------------

title1 NOBYLINE, TITLE in Data. / order=freq by group
and title2 Country Switzerland
------------------------------------------------------------
|                      |               crime               |
|                      |-----------------------------------|
|                      | theft  |robbery |assault |parking |
|                      |--------+--------+--------+--------|
|                      |   N    |   N    |   N    |   N    |
|----------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------|
|All                   |     441|     178|      70|      44|
|year                  |        |        |        |        |
|1980                  |     214|      84|      42|      27|
|1981                  |     227|      94|      28|      17|
------------------------------------------------------------

title1 NOBYLINE, TITLE in Data. / order=freq by group
and title2 Country Zeroland
------------------------------------------------------------
|                      |               crime               |
|                      |-----------------------------------|
|                      | theft  |robbery |assault |parking |
|                      |--------+--------+--------+--------|
|                      |   N    |   N    |   N    |   N    |
|----------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------|
|All                   |     432|     189|      74|      38|
|year                  |        |        |        |        |
|1980                  |     217|      89|      36|      25|
|1981                  |     215|     100|      38|      13|
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think your answer is right, if you only display one country at a time (`where country like 'S%' and year < 1984;`) but if you have several countries the columns should be ordered by the frequency over the years **for each country separately**. Can you help me with this?

Comment: The  `/order=freq` will be evaluated for each `BY` group.  Add `BY country` and you can remove `country` from the `table` statement.  You will have to first sort or index the data set by `country`.